# jQuery isFunction emit errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used jQuery's isFunction() to check if function defined or not.
But not working.

```js
if ( $.isFunction(oTable.fnDestroy()) ) {
    oTable.fnDestroy();
}
```

Please tell me how to make it works.
Thanks.

Comment: What *exactly* does "not working" mean? What is the error? (Note that the code *probably* should be `$.isFunction(oTable.fnDestroy)` without the extra `()`, but without seeing more code I don't know for sure.)

Comment: Most probably, at the point of execution of this code jquery isn't loaded into your browser. Make sure that you put your script tag that includes jQuery at the very top.

Comment: it says, that $ is not defined, that means, your jQuery library is not loaded propertly. So, you forgot to link your library, OR, and this happens from time to time, the order of your scripts is not correct and you are calling this your code BEFORE the code for linking the library is execured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By having the parenthesis after the function name you are calling the function and then passing the result to `$.isFunction`. You need to pass the actual function without invoking it for this to work.

```
if ( $.isFunction(oTable.fnDestroy) ) {
    oTable.fnDestroy();
}
```